# What can I use as a replacement for Curry Powder?

Tags: substitutions, curry

I do not like the taste of curry powder.  I have a recipe that calls for the use of this spice. What do you suggest that I can use in place of the curry powder?

Comment: Curry powder is a mixture of spices. Do you know what spice in particular you dislike?

Comment: In addition to the answer and comment already posted, you might find this of interest. http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/15760/curry-powder-mix?rq=1

Comment: You need to figure out what in the curry powder or paste it is that you don't like. To help us help you, telling us which curry powder or paste you don't like can help us to narrow down which spice it is that you find unpleasant. For instance, yellow curry is predominantly tumeric, so maybe that's what you don't like.

Comment: But then I have to ask, if you don't like "curry" in the most general sense, why are you following curry recipes? I am sure there are plenty of recipes that use almost all of the same ingredients but using a different spice profile.

Answer (score 5):

Curry powder is a blend of spices to some recipe or merchant's taste, as a convenience.   More traditionally, a particular blend of spices would be created for each individual dish, tailored to that dishes idiosyncrasies.

You can research one of [many current powder recipes](https://www.google.com/search?q=curry%20powder%20recipe&rlz=1C1CHKZ_enUS438US438&oq=curry%20powder%20recipe) on available, and simply make your own blend without whichever spice or spices it is that you do not enjoy.

Comment: That seems like a comment rather than an answer.  You should post a recipe for curry that you have tried.  Your answer just seems to be a link.

Comment: @blankip you miss the point. There is no such thing as one 'curry powder', so you should research one you like. We do not post recipes here in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Replace 1 teaspoon curry powder with 2 tablespoons chicken powder.

Comment: What is chicken powder? Do you mean boullion?

Answer (score 1):

True, it is a blend and different blends might work depending on one's tastes. There are lots of recipes/combinations, so research them if you want.  I am not much of a curry powder fan either, but I have tried making my own with good results. Chili powder used with a light hand, has worked well for me, I would suggest adapting the flavor profile from Asian to more of a Mexican one, if one does this. I have a recipe that I am going to make next, calling for two tablespoons of curry powder, and one pound of unseasoned ground meat just to give an idea of scale. That seems like a lot of chili powder, so probably not an equivalent substitution. I hope that helps
.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following items.These acts as a good replacement for curry powder

1/2 tsp turmeric
1 tsp ground cumin powder
1/2 tsp ground coriander powder
1/2 red chili powder, to taste

To know more you can check out the http://www.ask.com/question/what-is-a-good-substitute-for-curry-powder

Comment: While this is a good all-purpose curry powder replacement, it is such a good replacement that someone who doesn't like curry powder probably won't like this either.

Comment: In fact, this is not a substitute curry powder so much as a homemade curry powder.

Answer (score -1):

I usually just use curry paste, Indian or Asian curry paste in place of the powder form, and I find it does its job.. Just like you I dont like the powder, I find it over powering, where as the past its gives it a much better aroma and flavour...